# Should I use NULL or NA as default values for optional function parameters

Tags: r, function

I have a function which does extra things if a non-empty value is supplied to what otherwise would be an optional parameter. If the argument is not supplied, the function doesn't do anything extra.

Is it better to use `NA` or `NULL`? What are the advantages of either?

For example, if I use `NA`, then I can quickly check which arguments were not supplied by using: `is.na(as.list(environment()))` in the function body, which does not work with `is.null`.

**Here is an example of why I want to use `NA`**

I am trying to build an R connector to the [Geckoboard bar chart API](https://developer.geckoboard.com/#bar-chart). It has many optional arguments. If I do the following, it is very easy to use the package `jsonlite` to supply the optional arguments.

```
get_barchart_json <- function(data, x_axis = list(labels = NA, type = NA), y_axis = list(format = NULL, unit = NULL)){
    payload <- "{"
    textappend(payload) <- '"series": [{"data":['
    textappend(payload) <- paste0(data, collapse = ",")
    textappend(payload) <- ']}]'

    if(any(!is.na(x_axis))){

        textappend(payload) <- ","
        textappend(payload) <- jsonlite::toJSON(x_axis, auto_unbox = TRUE)

    }

    if(any(!is.na(y_axis))){

        textappend(payload) <- ","
        textappend(payload) <- jsonlite::toJSON(y_axis, auto_unbox = TRUE)

    }



    # finish construction
    textappend(payload) <- '}'

    return(payload)

}
```

which returns, for example:

```
cat(get_barchart_json(data = c(1,2,3,4), x_axis = list(labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), format = "text"), y_axis = list(format = 'decimal')))
```

NB: `textappend` is:

```
`textappend<-` <- function(payload, value){
 payload <- paste0(payload, value)    
 payload
}
```

Answer (score 8):

NA is for data values which are missing from data sets.  It will also propagate in places that NULL will not, as it can be type-coerced.   For an /optional/ value, use NULL.

I feel it's kind of an anti-pattern to allow missing argument values - it's hard to know which values you are leaving out.  With NULL, the 3rd argument is always the 3rd argument, etc...

See [NA vs. NULL](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "allow missing argument values"

Comment: Actually this is not quite a duplicate of, but the thing I'm talking about is already written up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370249/correct-way-to-specifiy-optional-arguments-in-r-functions

Comment: Thanks, very helpful link. So canonically it seems that one should use `NULL`, yet, using `NA` has its advantages as well.

Comment: Yup.  Plausibly within the realm of "preference", though now you have my opinion on which is cleaner. =)

Comment: "it's hard to know which values you are leaving out": that's why named arguments in function calls are a good thing!

Answer (score 5):

You actually have 3 options: `NA`, `NULL`, or no default.  Under most circumstances, `NULL` is the best option.

```
function(x, optional_arg = NULL)
{
  if(is.null(optional_arg))
  {
    # do something
  }
  # rest of body code
}
```

This doesn't work if you want users to be able do pass `NULL` as a legitimate value to `optional_arg`.  In that case, use

```
function(x, optional_arg)
{
  if(missing(optional_arg))
  {
    # do something
  }
  # rest of body code
}
```

A default of `NA` is only useful for cases where the optional arg should take one of three values, and it makes more sense to store it as a logical value rather than a string.

```
function(x, optional_arg = NA)
{
  if(is.na(optional_arg))
  {
    # do something
  } else if(optional_arg)
  {
    # do something else
  } else  # case of optional_arg == FALSE
  {
    # do a third thing
  }
  # rest of body code
}
```

Comment: Missing starts being an annoyance when you get to function that are deeply nested and you want to control some elements at a higher level, setting it to NULL is then much easier than writing the code to do multiple calls to the lower level function based on the higher up parameters supplied.

Comment: @Hansi. Yep.  Like I said, `NULL` is usually the best option.

Answer (score 0):

As Hansi mentioned in the comments, relying on missing is fine for interactive use, but is annoying for programmatic use with nested functions that pass arguments to downwards. Consider the following minimum example.

Suppose we have a function that does something special when `arg2` is missing. We check using the standard `missing` approach.

```
> func1 = function(arg1, arg2) {
  if (missing(arg2)) print("no arg2")
  print(arg1)
  }
> func1("abc")
[1] "no arg2"
[1] "abc"
```

This works fine. However, what if we call this from another function that passes arguments on and has a default?

```
> func2 = function(arg1, arg2 = "def") {
  func1(arg1 = arg1, arg2 = arg2)
  }
> func2("abc")
[1] "abc"
> func2("abc", arg2 = )
[1] "abc"
> func2("abc", arg2 = NULL)
[1] "abc"
> func2("abc", arg2 = NA)
[1] "abc"
```

We can't seem to trigger the special feature when `arg2` is missing because it's not easy to set the `arg2` to be missing from another function that never had a missing argument. [Maybe not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557805/passing-missing-argument-from-function-to-function-in-r).

[Also discussed on this blogpost](https://www.r-bloggers.com/function-argument-lists-and-missing/).