# Multiple match.arg in helper function for list inputs

Tags: r, list, input, match, user-input

Disclaimer: I already found a working solution while I was writing this question. However, I am not convinced that it is a good one. And since I wrote a comment in a different thread (linked below) that I have this problem I am going to post my problem and my solution here in case someone else is having the same issue or an even better solution than mine.

---

I am currently implementing a function which has multiple input variables of the same name for different "parts" which can have different input values. I decided to use a list for each part and specified the individual inputs within those lists. The details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77666827/22606447

Now I would like to use match.arg on the character variables, and I would like to write a function for that as all the "parts" use the same argument choices, so I don't want to write them for each list input separately. This is what I have so far:

```
match_arguments <- function(argument_list, choices_list) {
  matched_args <- mapply(match.arg, argument_list, choices_list) 
  return(as.list(matched_args))
}


part1_fun <- function(x = 1, y = TRUE, z = c("abc", "zyx"), another = c("aat", "bbt")) {
  arguments_to_match <- list(z = z, another = another)
  choices <- formals(part1_fun)[c("z", "another")]
  remaining_arguments <- formals(part1_fun)[!(names(formals(part1_fun)) %in% names(choices))]
  matched_arguments <- match_arguments(arguments_to_match, choices)
  matched_arguments <- lapply(matched_arguments, as.character)
  
  result <- c(remaining_arguments, matched_arguments)
  
  return(result)
}
```

to also show the remainder of the small example (unfinished for part2):

```
part2_fun <- function(x = 2, y = FALSE, z = "bcd"){
  list(x = x, y = y, z = z)
}


myFUN <- function(part1_args, part2_args){
  part1_input <- do.call(part1_fun, part1_args)
  part2_input <- do.call(part2_fun, part2_args)


  print(part1_input)
  print(part2_input)
}

part1_output <- myFUN(
  part1_args = list(x = 3, z = "z", another = "a"),
  part2_args = list(y = TRUE)
)
```

The issue I originally had is that the line
`choices <- formals(part1_fun)[c("z", "another")]` returns the choices not as character vectors but as "language" objects.

```
List of 2
 $ z      : language c("abc", "zyx")
 $ another: language c("aat", "bbt")
```

Which leads to the output:

```
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] TRUE

$z
"zyx"()

$another
"aat"()
```

Now the line `matched_arguments <- lapply(matched_arguments, as.character)` in `part1_fun` solves this by converting it to a character vector but going this detour seems unnecessary complicated.

Is there a better solution?